# REST API - Automatically make requests by clicking submit

Tags: php, ajax, rest, api

I have this script but I don't know how to run it automatically when I click submit button

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var cbIntegrationId = "xxxxxx";
      var clientId = "xxxxx";
      var clientSecret = "xxxxxxx";
      var tableName = "xxxxxx";

      //Get access token
      $.post(
         "https://" + cbIntegrationId + ".caspio.com/oauth/token",{
          grant_type: "client_credentials",
          client_id: clientId,
          client_secret: clientSecret
          },
        function(cbAuth){
//Run POST call
$.ajax({
  url: "https://" + cbIntegrationId + ".caspio.com/rest/v2/tables/" + tableName + "/records?response=rows",
  type: 'POST',
  'data': JSON.stringify({"UniqueID":"34","Full_Name": "Name_Value"}), //Define record values
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + cbAuth.access_token, //Extracts the access token from the initial authorization call
    "Content-Type": "application/json", //Required, otherwise 415 error is returned
    "Accept": "application/json"
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.Result); //Check the console to view the new added row
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log(data.responseJSON); //Check the console to view error message if any
  }
  });
   }
);
    </script>
```

This is the form

```
<form method="" action="">
    Full Name: 
    <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I would like to know how do I run the script automatically and get a success message (true or false)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form method="" action="" onSubmit="callApi()">
    Full Name: 
    <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

```
function callApi() {

  //Get access token
      $.post(
         "https://" + cbIntegrationId + ".caspio.com/oauth/token",{
          grant_type: "client_credentials",
          client_id: clientId,
          client_secret: clientSecret
          },
        function(cbAuth){
//Run POST call
$.ajax({
  url: "https://" + cbIntegrationId + ".caspio.com/rest/v2/tables/" + tableName + "/records?response=rows",
  type: 'POST',
  'data': JSON.stringify({"UniqueID":"34","Full_Name": "Name_Value"}), //Define record values
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + cbAuth.access_token, //Extracts the access token from the initial authorization call
    "Content-Type": "application/json", //Required, otherwise 415 error is returned
    "Accept": "application/json"
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.Result); //Check the console to view the new added row
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log(data.responseJSON); //Check the console to view error message if any
  }
  });
   }
);

}
    </script>
```

Maybe you need to change `UniqueID` and `Full_Name`. If Full_Name is the user input on the form, you can get like this:

```
$('input[name="full_name"]').val()
```